# I want to embed YouTube videos. What should I do?

Tags: discussion

I usually include a YouTube link when I post a question.
But I want to embed YouTube videos.
What should I do?

Comment: I think you should format a question in another way then. Question should rely on information which can be gathered from the question body without any videos (short gifs as exception). YT videos can't be embedded on this site and in my opinion shouldn't be. If you really want you can include a link to it but summarize its contents in text

Comment: Related: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/93/599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BSE does not have YT embeds on purpose.
It all comes down to two types of posts we are trying to avoid: Link only posts, and "fix this" posts. Adding a video embed would just worsen both problems.

A video *embed* does not fit well in the SE system. A post could too easily be totally dependent on the video (link only), which would just make the [this kind](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/2217) of problem worse.

So what should you do? Write your question, then **link** to the youtube videos. Remember any external source (like youtube or blend-exchange) must be supplemental. Generally, a question should be understandable just from reading the question. If a video is really necessary to get the information across (in *most* cases it isn't), then by all means link to it. But under no circumstances should should your question be a video and *"See video for the problem."*

Same goes for answers. When you write an answer, write it first then *link* to the youtube video. Remember **any external source (like youtube) must be supplemental.** Your answer should still be helpful and understandable on its own, not dependent on any links. If a YT video helps get the information across better, then by all means link to it. But under no circumstances should a video be your answer.

Comment: It would be nice to have a button in the formatting tools that does the thumbnail link method.  While we're at it, it would be nice to see this for blend file uploads too, but I am aware of the difficulties and reasons which may prevent this.