# Is it possible to post .webm videos on the Blender Stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I know how to make .gifs but they have no sounds.
I also know how to make .webs which do have sound.

Is it possible to attach a .webm on a post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible network-wide. Only images and `.gif` animations can be uploaded in Stack Exchange Q&A posts.

Speaking of *externally hosted* multimedia content, included via embed, this is only possible for YouTube videos on [four specific stack exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/368912). Blender.StackExchange seems not to be interested in that feature anyway: see [this post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93/should-we-enable-video-embedding).

Answer (score 5):

As I said it somewhere before on meta I will say it again now.

**We need .webm support!** *Without sound.*

For the sake of:

- quality,
- bandwidth (!),
- comfort - creation and watching (controls),
- smooth playback,
- lack of glitches,
- editing,
- and again bandwidth and quality.

This example has around: **.gif ~835kB**, **.apng ~740kB** and **.webm ~185kB**

[image: example]

> .webm is around 80% smaller than .gif in this example.

It's something. Right? Considering over bloated internet this is a big thing.

As much as I personally prefer fully written answer, it is undeniable that there are things that you cannot describe, there are ones that are just clearer with animated proof. We have them, we need them, we will still use them. So why not use  nicer, smoother and considerably smaller way?

Comment: I am very much in favour of this. Imgur already convert all uploaded gifs to h264 videos, it also support native video uploads. So even if they don't want to support webm, they can easily support mp4s. Why isn't this being considered?

Comment: @OmarAhmad I've no idea. It's 2019 and we are still using ~30 years old technology - just because. I cannot find a single positive why gif's are better than short videos.

Comment: I am guessing it is to avoid "video only answers" with "lengthy tutorials", or worse questions that are just a dreadfully long video instead explaining an issue succinctly . But I do agree, some times it is very hard to explain something withing the confines of a 2Mb GIF

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos as I said in my post and proved in my answers, I prefer written ones, but. If we have 2Mb .gif, lets switch to 2Mb .webm. There are only pros to this decision and you cannot fit full tutorial in 2Mb, or can you? :D

Comment: Probably not, but I can see many newbies posting videos of ["look at my issue", how do I solve this?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this) Like I said, I would holehartedly welcome the change, just pointing out the probable reasons why it hasn't been implemented.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos They can do this now by posting numerous .gifs or just pasting links (like they sometimes do). This we cannot avoid. But we can ease life for ourselves.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. We have no video support.

Further I would caution you on how you use a video. Sure you can make a video put it on youtube and link to it. But that whole video should be supplemental to the written answer. If a video helps explain things (and sometimes it does) then in no way am I saying that you should not have a video, just that the video should not be your answer.
And that is why we do not have any kind of video embed support.

Answer (score 3):

Note that this site also supports animated png files:

[image]

However, I might be wrong but the support of apng also depends on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want to upload videos, but they are in different formats beside gif, you can go to site Ezgif and convert your mp4 videos to gif. 
https://ezgif.com

If you have ffmpeg videos, go to this site below.
https://www.online-convert.com
Choose "Video convertor" and select "Convert to MP4." Upload video and hit "Start converson" button. Don't bother with settings below that. 
Once you have created MP4 copy, go to Ezgif and convert it to gif.

At Ezgif, you can crop videos, optionally.