# What Animation FIle Types Should Be Used in Questions/Answers?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm sure this has to be a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find where it's answered -- **a link to the existing answer would be appreciated!**

For still images I've used jpgs for all my questions and answers so far, and for animations I've seen that animated gifs under 2meg can be used.  Are there any other file types that are recommended for explanatory animations in questions and answers on the Blender Stackexchange?

Comment: GIFs are the only accepted animated file type. See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/964 https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-post-gifs-on-this-site/405#405

Comment: Although both of those links (I'd only found one of 'em, thx!) are very informative on animated gif usage here, neither says that animated gifs are the only animated file type accepted here (that I can see).  Also, they're both over five years old -- that's still current?  Stackexchange's animations are hosted on imgur, searching animation file types "imgur" turns up several formats that are probably more efficient for this site's purposes.

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: That's a bit frustrating.  However, it seems that my question is not a duplicate.  If you'd be kind enough to put your first comment into an answer then I'll checkmark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here:

[Is it possible to post .webm videos on the Blender Stack exchange?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/is-it-possible-to-post-webm-videos-on-the-blender-stack-exchange)

“Only images and .gif animations can be uploaded in Stack Exchange Q&A posts.” - Nicola Sap

The points cgslav made in their answer are even better now, three years later.  StackExchange graphics (still and animated) are hosted on Imgur -- I just rendered a webm in Blender, bigger, longer, and still under the 2meg limit, than the best I was able to as a gif [for this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256290/how-to-make-silver-color-without-hdri-image/256305#256305).  I put it [up on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTFG7.jpg) with no trouble.